# How to modify the length of "headtoprule" when using \newgeometry in pst-doc class

Tags: margins, koma-script, document-classes, geometry

everybody, I have a little problem modifying the margins using the 'pst-doc' class. The default margins look like this:
[image: DefaultOutput]

But, by modifying the margins using this MWE:

```
\documentclass[11pt,english,BCOR10mm,DIV10,bibliography=totoc,parskip=false,smallheadings,
               headexclude,footinclude=false,oneside]{pst-doc}
\AfterCalculatingTypearea{\newgeometry{top=0.5in, bottom=0.3in, left=2in, right=0.7in,footskip=0.2in,headheight=1cm,headsep=0.27cm}}
\recalctypearea
\usepackage[toc]{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\title{\texttt{TEST}}
\subtitle{A minor test}
\author{Pablo}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

The output looks like this:
[image: wrong]

The margins are correct, but, "headrule" extends further than I expect.
How do I change this value to match the width of the text?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `\KOMAoptions{headwidth=text,headsepline=:text}` or `\KOMAoptions{headwidth=text,headsepline=.4pt:text}` after `\newgeometry` in the argument of `\AfterCalculatingTypearea`:

```latex
\documentclass[11pt,english,
  BCOR=10mm,DIV=10,% <- changed
  bibliography=totoc,parskip=false,
  headings=small,% <- changed
  headinclude=false,% <- changed
  footinclude=false,oneside]{pst-doc}
\AfterCalculatingTypearea{%
  \newgeometry{top=0.5in, bottom=0.3in, left=2in, right=0.7in,footskip=0.2in,headheight=1cm,headsep=0.27cm}%
  \KOMAoptions{headwidth=text,headsepline=:text}% <- added
}
\recalctypearea
\usepackage[toc]{blindtext}
\begin{document}
\title{\texttt{TEST}}
\subtitle{A minor test}
\author{Pablo}
\maketitle
\blinddocument
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: You saved my day, thank you very much.

Comment: Now that I notice, the page numbers are missing, can you see that?

Comment: Oh, option `headwidth` must be changed too: `headwidth=text`. See my updated answer.

Comment: Thank you again!